# The image quality reduced when capture

Tags: java, android

I have finished the camera module for my text recognizer app, but the image quality is too low, the Text detector engine sometimes cant get any text from image. It still look good in preview, my phone is Pixel XL, so i think it not the camera problem. Maybe when i pass the image's bitmap to Text detector activity, it reduced the quality, how can i recover?

am using intent.putExtra to pass the bitmap, this is my code:

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Intent  intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetTextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

and this is in the receiver:

```
 byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("key");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    imgCaptured.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    //text recognizer
    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w("MainActivity_capture", "Detector is not available");
    } else {
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
        SparseArray<TextBlock> items = textRecognizer.detect(frame);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
            sb.append(item.getValue());
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        tvGetText.setText(sb);
    }
```

Comment: Hi If I need to do something like this, First I will store the captured image in my mobile local storage and get the saved path. I will use that saved path to access the image. Please try this and let me know your feedback.
Thanks!

Comment: this is just a function in my text detector app, so i dont want to save the image into local storage, just need it at the time user want to get text, is there any other way around?

Comment: OK, First save the image to local storage, Do whatever do you want to do with that image after that delete it. Another solution capture the image convert it into Base64 String, Parse that created string to your other activity, again convert Base64 String to the Image file.  I think the first solution is easy for you. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure those solutions will not reduce the quality? i think i will try to convert to base64

Comment: If you use the second solution (Base 64 String), It reduces the quality little bit. you can use `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, <ByteArrayOutputStream>);` to compress the image. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that when you convert your image to Base64 String and Base64 String to Image do that in a separate thread (Use `AsyncTask` or `RxJava`). Thanks!

Comment: thank you, but i dont understand why i need to do the conversion in another thread?

Comment: Please follow this link
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads
Thanks!